# sublime text replace whitespaces around letters

Tags: regex

I have the following text:  "`th i s morn i ng a fo x i s ru n n ing`"

I want to remove the wrong white spaces to get this: "`this morning a fox is running`"

I tried this in the search field in Sublime text:

```
(\s(?!a)[a-z]\s)
```

but then I don't know what to put in the Replace field.

Comment: How do you know which space is "wrong"?

Comment: every time a letter other than "a" alone is surrounded by a whitespace.

Comment: Alright, well have a peek at non-capturing groups. You should be able to replace the actual capture groups with `\1` or some other placeholder.

Comment: By that definition, the space between `s` and `morn` will be removed.

Comment: "***but then I don't know what to put in the Replace field.***" You should leave the substitution field empty, also, your example doesn't have a pattern, even if you say "***every time a letter other than "a" alone is surrounded by a whitespace***" What about `is` and other verbs? I'm finding difficult to understand your goal with this.

Comment: "is" is 2 letters surrounded by whitespace. That should not fall within the pattern. But in this sentence "do y o u se e a mo n k ey" every time a letter other a is surrounded by whitespaces, the whitespace after it should be deleted

Comment: Not clear what the conditions are. If you take `do y o u se e a mo n k ey` and remove whitespaces surrounding alone letters other than `a`, it will become `doyousee a monkey`. Please provide more details.

Comment: Also if you just remove the space *AFTER* the alone letter it will become `do youse e a mo nkey`